# NextGEN Gallery - album showing too much space with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, border, nextgen-gallery

I have a problem with the NextGEN Gallery albums on my site (`tornaia.com/bilder/`) in Chrome. The borders around the album-thumbnail are too big, so you have to scroll all the way down to get to the next album. In Firefox and IE it shows

Here I have a schreenshot of how it is in chrome:
(http://tornaia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Chrome.jpg)

And here is how it is in Firefox (how it should be looking):
(http://tornaia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Firefox.jpg)

Any idea why this happens? Or better: how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I solved it myself :)

I simply put

```
.ngg-album {
height:130px;
}
```

in the `style.css` file. Now it works with IE, Firefox and Chrome. Hopefully all the other browsers as well :